# How to interpret A VAR model, Method: OLS

Tags: least-squares, autocorrelation, vector-autoregression

I am working on a VAR using an OLS model as can be seen below. I am however having difficulties interpreting the results. I think to understand the basic concept of an equation being significant below a certain p-value but it seems that the results are flawed. For instance in the case of "Results for equation Rt", should not L1.RT be 0 or 1.

And what is the use of BIC HQIC and FPE.

All help is appreciated.

[image: VAR results]

Comment: Which column do you refer to and why do you believe results should be 0 or 1?